# What's the proper verb for opening a web page?

Tags: verbs, word-requests

What's the proper verb to use when you want to ask somebody to open (or load up) a certain link on their browser?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can try:

- リンクを開{ひら}く
- リンクを開{あ}ける
- リンクをたどる (follow the link)
- リンクをクリックする (click the link)
- サイトを訪れる (visit a site)

Of course don't forget to conjugate them into the required requesting/commanding forms.

Answer (score 3):

Just ~を見てください is possible, I think.

Also, some slightly politer forms that you might see around:

~をご覧{らん}ください (please see)

~をご参考{さんこう}ください (please refer to)